# ImportError: cannot import name 'BaseOuputParser' from 'langchain.schema'

Tags: python, openai-api, langchain

Hello i am trying to run this following code but i am getting an error;

```
from langchain.schema import BaseOuputParser
```

Error;

> ImportError: cannot import name 'BaseOuputParser' from
> 'langchain.schema'

My langchain version is ; **'0.1.7'**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite simple, you have a typo. `BaseOuputParser` vs `BaseOutputParser`. Missing a t.

Voted to close this question based on that due to that, but if fixing it does not solve the problem, then the issue is elsewhere.

Comment: Oh, sorry yes it was a typo :( thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

The error you're encountering, ImportError: cannot import name 'BaseOuputParser' from 'langchain.schema', suggests that there's a typo in your import statement or the BaseOuputParser class does not exist in the version of langchain you're using (0.1.7).

First, ensure that there's no typo in the class name. It's possible that the correct class name might be BaseOutputParser (with an extra 't' in "Output") rather than BaseOuputParser.

pip install --upgrade langchain

Comment: Oh, sorry yes it was a typo thank you!